# Is There any way to Stop Playing previous Notification Sound if sound is 24 seconds of duration?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, swift5

I am currently Working on an app that has a custom notification tune of 24 seconds duration. The problem I am facing is when receiving two Push Notifications with a little time difference and two sounds start playing...
iS there any way to stop playing previously playing notification sound?
what I have tried yet programmatically volume Down but it that's useless.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Tune your server so that it checks the time of the last notification and doesn't send a new one or sends a new one with a modified sound parameter in a notification content.
2. Don't add a sound parameter to the notification, but play sounds in a NotificationService Extension. You can use it to change and process push notifications as you want before they are shown to the user.

Comment: Sending a new notification with no sound didn't work... !